# How to use SharePoint Migration API without uploading data to Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

Is there any possibility to upload data to SharePoint Online using Migration API, without uploading package to Azure Storage. [I have referred some Blogs and they are suggesting to upload package to Azure Storage via Powershell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sposupport/2017/09/29/migrating-content-to-sharepoint-online-via-powershell/)

Comment: I feel curious trying to understand your question, are you migrating local folders and/file shares into SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you can use is the direct migration using PowerShell, it will not use the Migration API and of course, no Azure will be required.

I've created a custom solution for migration, it supports metadata and allows you to migrate file shares and local folders, not sure if it will be helpful for you but take a look:

https://github.com/MrDrSushi/SPOPSM